# Помогите найти информацию по create-react-component with sass/scss

Tags: reactjs

Помню что создавал компоненты через командную строку, + в нем был `scss`. Не могу нагуглить, даже в документации не могу об этом найти? Плиз, Хэлп. Дайте ссылок где это описывается

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-component-folder

Comment: это почти то, что нужно, только чтоб в папке был `style.scss`. Мне кажется это было из коробки `create-react-app`. Не в курсе?

Comment: ну так читайте доку. Там есть scss. -s, --scss       Adds .scss file to component

Comment: кажется нужно просто настроить вебпак чтобы он понимал scss и проблема решена